# Jenkinsfile setting stageResult variable based on conditions

Tags: shell, if-statement, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to script a Jenkinsfile in Declarative Syntax, requirement here is if set environment variables are not a match then pipeline stage should be depict as "Aborted" but the build status could be either Aborted or unstable, on Jenkins online documentation and from Snippet Generator did see the following style

```
catchError(buildResult: 'ABORTED', stageResult: 'ABORTED') {
    // some block
}
```

***catchError*** does not serve my purpose as it is appropriate for use when the script inside the stage does not return true or if there is an execution error, although default ***when*** condition in Jenkins Declarative Syntax is appropriate, Jenkins does not allow setting stage result to 'ABORTED'

```
when {
                expression {
                    SCM_BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(master|QA)/
                }
                expression{
                    ENVIRONMENT ==~ /(QA)/
                }
                allOf{
                    environment ignoreCase: true,name: 'PRODUCT_NAME' , value: 'PRODUCT-1'
                }
            }
```

Please view the Sample Jenkinsfile below using if and else format
***Sample Jenkinsfile***

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'master'
        }
    }
    environment{
        ENVIRONMENT = "QA"
        PRODUCT_NAME = "PRODUCT-1"
        SCM_BRANCH_NAME = "master"
    }
    stages{
        stage('Testing-1') {
            when{
            expression{
                    ENVIRONMENT ==~ /(QA)/
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (PRODUCT_NAME == PRODUCT-1){
                        sh """
                        echo "Reached Here ${ENVIRONMENT} - ${PRODUCT_NAME} - ${SCM_BRANCH_NAME}"
                        // do testing for product 1
                        """  
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        stageResult = 'ABORTED'
                        echo "PRODUCT not Available for Testing"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Testing-2'){
            steps{
                sh '''
                    echo "Reached Second Stage"
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions of how to implement the scenario that if conditions are not met set the ***stageResult*** as Abort, any suggestions either with a plugin or with a sample notation script is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet worked for me. You can use catch error block and throw the error from that block when some condition met. You can also catch the exception in the post stage failure section.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'master'
        }
    }
    environment{
        ENVIRONMENT = "QA"
        PRODUCT_NAME = "PRODUCT-1"
        SCM_BRANCH_NAME = "master"
    }
    stages{
        stage('Testing-1') {
            when{
            expression{
                    ENVIRONMENT ==~ /(QA)/
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'ABORTED'){
                        if (PRODUCT_NAME != PRODUCT-1) {
                            error ("PRODUCT not Available for Testing")
                        }
                        sh """
                        echo "Reached Here ${ENVIRONMENT} - ${PRODUCT_NAME} - ${SCM_BRANCH_NAME}"
                        // do testing for product 1
                        """  
                    }
                }
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    echo "Something Failed and error has been catched"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Testing-2'){
            steps{
                sh '''
                    echo "Reached Second Stage"
                '''
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiruba for your suggestion

Comment: your suggestion is working and appropriate, Thanks again

Comment: Good to hear, please accept the answer if you are happy.